# Reshaping tables in pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

Below is an extract of a dataframe which I have created my merging multiple query log dataframes:

```
                keyword               hits         date         average time
1               the cat sat on        10           10-Jan       10
2               who is the sea        5            10-Jan       1.2
3               under the earth       30           1-Dec        2.5
4               what is this          100          1-Feb        9
```

Is there a way I can pivot the data using Pandas so that rows are daily dates (e.g. 1-Jan, 2-Jan etc.) and the corresponding 1 column to each date is the daily sum of hits (sum of the hits for that day e.g. sum of hits for 1-Jan) divided by the monthly sum of hits (e.g. for the whole of Jan) for that month (i.e. the month normalised daily hit percentage for each day)

Comment: We're happy to help, but you didn't post any code or any error messages, so it's not clear what your problem is or what's confusing you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback DSM - have just edited the question to clarify. Let me know if its still ambiguos.

Comment: To help others with the sample problem, consider changing the title of your question. "Pivoting" means something else. Maybe "Normalized tallies in pandas?"

Comment: Thanks for that Dan - just done it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the dates so we can extract the month later.

```
In [99]: df.date = df.date.apply(pd.Timestamp)

In [100]: df
Out[100]: 
           keyword  hits                date  average time
1   the cat sat on    10 2013-01-10 00:00:00          10.0
2   who is the sea     5 2013-01-10 00:00:00           1.2
3  under the earth    30 2013-12-01 00:00:00           2.5
4     what is this   100 2013-02-01 00:00:00           9.0
```

Group by day and sum the hits.

```
In [101]: daily_totals = df.groupby('date').hits.sum()

In [102]: daily_totals
Out[102]: 
date
2013-01-10     15
2013-02-01    100
2013-12-01     30
Name: hits, dtype: int64
```

Group by month, and divide each row (each daily total) by the sum of all the daily totals in that month.

```
In [103]: normalized_totals = daily_totals.groupby(lambda d: d.month).transform(lambda x: float(x)/x.sum())

In [104]: normalized_totals
Out[104]: 
date
2013-01-10    1
2013-02-01    1
2013-12-01    1
Name: hits, dtype: int64
```

Your simple example only gave one day in each month, so all these are 1.

Comment: Dan, how do I do this (the normalisation) per keyword? Max.

Comment: To do it per keyword alone, change the argument of ``gropuby`` to ``'keyword``'. To do daily normalization broken down by keyword in addition to day, use a list as the argument: ``['keyword', lambda d: d.month]``. (That might not work -- you may need to spell it out as ``[daily_totals.keyword, lambda d: d.month]``.) The result will be multi-indexed on date and keyword.